# How do I prevent others from using my app key for HERE maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm using HERE maps, and it shows my app_id and app_code in the html code. I want to use this app_id for my website only. There is a setting in the platform that allows me to set domains to use the app_id (Secure app credentials against a specific domain). I added my domain on the secured domain list. However it doesn't seem to work, for example, I want to use this code for my website A, then I copy the same code to another website B, and it still works on website B.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="map" style="height:550px;width:720px;"></div>

<script>
    //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'devportal-demo-20180625',
  app_code: '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ',
      useHTTPS: true
    });
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
      tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
      ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
    });

    //Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers); 




function setUpClickListener(map) {
  map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
            evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
     addMarker(coord);
  });
}

function addMarker(coordinates){
    var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:coordinates.lat, lng: coordinates.lng});
    map.addObject(marker);

    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:coordinates.lat, lng: coordinates.lng}, {
            content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
           });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
}

setUpClickListener(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks as if this is not possible? The only protections available seems to be the secure domain list. Might I ask for an eample of what you have entered as the secure domain on the HERE developer portal and the domain of the site that will be utilising it? obfuscate it with a fake domain if required.

I had a quick play and it looks as if it's more intended for nodejs work. Javascript in the browser is executed clientside so the secure domain list wont do anything as it is the client executing it i'm pretty sure. I don't think this will work for your intended purpose.